# How do I make org-agenda-fortnight-view the default in custom block agenda?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I've got the following configuration set up for displaying my current agenda and tagged todo items:

```
  (setq org-agenda-custom-commands
        '(("g" "Plan today"
           ((agenda "")
            (tags-todo "Computer")
            (tags-todo "Online")
            ...
            )
           )))
```

When called with `C-c a g` this shows the agenda for the current week. I can switch to the current fortnight using `v t` which is org-agenda-fortnight-view, but when calling the agenda again, it switches back to week view.

What should I do to make the fortnight-view the default?

Answer (score 2):

The related questions section here on SO actually provided me with a pointer to the solution, which is to set the org-agenda-span variable/option like so:

```
 (setq org-agenda-custom-commands
        '(("g" "Plan today"
           ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-span 14)))
            (tags-todo "Computer")
            ...
            )
           )))
```